# Create a type that is a subset of an other type

Tags: haskell, types

How can you create a type that is a subset of an other type? I want a string type that only contains alphanumeric characters.

So I want something like this

```
type AlphNumString = [AlphaNumChar]
data AlphaNumChar = ???? filter (isAlphaNum) Char ????
```

Comment: `filter` isn't a *type*, it's a *function*.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, True, filter is a function and not a type. What I was hoping to steer to was a way to derive types from other types given some condition.

Comment: @Henk Sadly Haskell doesn't have a way to really *trivially* do this. Smart constructors are about the best you can do. (As a silly example, imagine an `Int` subtype that only holds prime numbers. How the hell does the compiler know what a prime number is? Clearly this has to happen in user code...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way to do this is with so-called "[smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors)".

First, you define a new type that's identical to the old one:

```
newtype AlphNumString = X String
```

Next, you write the smart constructor itself:

```
toAlphNumString :: String -> AlphNumString
toAlphNumString txt = X (filter isAlphNum txt)
```

Finally, you make it so `toAlphNumString` is *the only* way to create an `AlphNumString`.

```
module Foo (AlphNumString (), toAlphNumString, ...) where ...
```

Note that this does *not* allow you to use an `AlphNumString` like a normal `String`; you can't create "subtypes" like that in Haskell. So you'll also need another function

```
fromAlphNumString :: AlphNumString -> String
fromAlphNumString (X txt) = txt
```

Comment: For the specific case I'm working on I do not mind this limitations. However, I can image situations where to use of the strings functions would be useful. Is there a way to automatically wrap these functions? Would something like the IsString class (Data.String) be of any help?

Comment: For *strings* specifically, if you turn on the `OverloadedStrings` extension. And *all* this does is automatically wrap literal strings; it doesn't make the types the same, it just makes it easier to type in literals.

Comment: @ MathematicalOrchid
, this is great; when you Google this most of the results imply that you can't do this and don't mention this technique.

Answer (score 3):

This concept of types that are "subsets" of other types based on some predicate is called refinement types. For Haskell, this is implemented as [LiquidHaskell](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/about/).

However, I would consider this an ongoing research. In practice, I would go with a newtype and dynamic checks, as MathematicalOrchid describes in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a dependently typed language (which Haskell is not, yet) you could use dependent pairs for this.

```
data Sigma : (t : Type) -> (t -> Type) -> Type where
  MkSigma : (x : t) -> p x -> Sigma t p

data IsAlphaNum : (c : Char) -> Type where
  MkIsAlphaNum : isAlphaNum c = True -> IsAlphaNum c
```

Then `Sigma Char IsAlphNum` would be a type representing alphanumeric characters. Each element of that type would consist of a character and a proof that the character is alphanumeric.

Comment: The technique is called "[viewing](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/view/view.ps)".